# Why does a distinct count after a MergeSort join on a Spark dataframe of Vectors give a non-deterministic results

Tags: apache-spark

A spark inner SortMerge Join on using a column containing a ml Vector appears to give non-deterministic and inaccurate result on larger datasets.

I was using the [approxNearestNeighbors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel@approxNearestNeighbors(dataset:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],key:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector,numNearestNeighbors:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]) method of BucketRandomLSH projection of Spark v2.4.3, and discovered it gives different numbers of results for large data sets.

This problem only appears when executing a SortMerge join; a broadcast join gives the same result every time.

I tracked the problem down to the join on the LSH hash keys. A reproducible example is below...

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import scala.util.Random
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
//create a large dataframe containing an Array (length two) of ml Vectors of length one.
val df =  Seq.fill(30000)(
        (java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString,
          Seq(
                  Vectors.dense(Random.nextInt(10).toDouble),                                                                 
                  Vectors.dense(Random.nextInt(10).toDouble))
             )
      ).toDF

//ensure it's caches
df.cache.count()

//positional explode the vector column
val dfExploded = df.select(col("*"), posexplode(col("_2")))

// now self join on the exploded 'col' and 'pos' fields
dfExploded.join(dfExploded, Seq("pos","col")).drop("pos","col").distinct.count
```

Different result each time...

```
scala>dfExploded.join(dfExploded,Seq("pos","col")).drop("pos","col").distinct.count
res139: Long = 139663581                                                        

scala>dfExploded.join(dfExploded,Seq("pos","col")).drop("pos","col").distinct.count
res140: Long = 156349630
```

Comment: interesstingly, if you use Scalas `Seq[Double]` instead of Sparks `Vector`, its deterministic. I think the problem could be your join conditions where you compare two dense-vector entries (which are floating point)

Comment: You are right! thanks. I guess the question is why is can't two `Vector` be compared successfully ? The LSH algorithm is broken by this (see this [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7955b3962ac46b89564e0613db7bea98a1478bf2/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L209))